# Setting background to all activities on click

Tags: java, android, image, android-activity, background

I have an app that allows users to change the background. I have an activity in which users get to pick the background that they want from a list of images shown. My only problem is that i don't know how to set the image that they pick as the background for all of the other activities and also how i can save the information so when they get out of the app and come back in to the app, they would still see the image that they set as the background. any help or advice will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: What background are you talking about? The background in your app? The Android wallpaper?

Comment: if you change only background then better to use of FragmentActivity.
You need to change only Fragment Activity background.
Also store your data in local using Shared Preferences.

Comment: Yea i want to change the background of the activities.

Comment: This is the code that i have. ImageView sunrise = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sunrise_background_options);
  final RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background_preview_layout);
  
  sunrise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    preview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beach_sunrise);
    This only sets the image as the background the current activity, So m wondering if m able to set a background to other activities from the current activity

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main problem is how to persist the background image setting and share it across different activities then [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) may be the best solution. Essentially, it allows you to save simple key value pairs (perhaps the name of the image file in your case?) which is shared across activities and persisted across instances of your application.

Comment: Thank you, ill look at it and hopefully i can find it.